# Mapbox failed last location React native

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to use Mapbox on my app, few days ago it was doing great but then on my react-native project I get this error: Mapbox Error last update unavailable on Android but not on iOS, I'm using Mapbox.UserLocation component like this:

```
 <MapboxGL.MapView style={{ flex: 1 }} 
    compassEnabled={false} 
    attributionEnabled={false} 
    zoomEnabled 
    logoEnabled={false} 
    onUserLocationUpdate={this.onLocationUpdate}>
        <MapboxGL.UserLocation 
              onUpdate= {this.onLocationUpdate} />
</MapboxGL.MapView>
```

I'm running and Flipper 0.52.0

```
"react-native": "^0.62.2",
"@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.1.0-rc.2",
```

[image: ERROR LINK]

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by changing the location settings and changing the highAccuracy option and enable it.

Comment: Yea, though I have not come across this scenario but I believe this might work...